# A problem occurred configuring project ':cloud_firestore' //closed

Tags: firebase, flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test, flutter-plugin

My project is going very well, but after adding some dependencies I am facing an error message.

```
flutter clean 
flutter upgrade 
flutter pub get
```

are not working in my case.

Here is the error message :

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':cloud_firestore'.
> Could not open proj remapped class cache for avok974yim47bw7y5uibkvy5o (C:\Users\Lenovo\.gradle\caches\5.6.2\scripts-remapped\build_7tod23iwanax3gvxok38cccwk\avok974yim47bw7y5uibkvy5o\projc2aa9a77c8f22767dac24ce473ea6e20).
   > Unexpected lock protocol found in lock file. Expected 3, found 0.
> Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
   > Could not get unknown property 'android' for project ':cloud_firestore' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
   > Could not find method implementation() for arguments [project ':firebase_core'] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
   > Could not find method implementation() for arguments [project ':cloud_firestore_web'] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s
Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)
```

**dependencies**

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
  animated_text_kit: ^2.0.0
  firebase_core: ^0.4.4+2
  firebase_auth: ^0.15.5+2
  cloud_firestore: ^0.13.4
```

**build.gradle**

```
dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.2'

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
```

this are the dependencies of app gradle
**build.gradle()**

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
    
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Comment: By deleting the folder located in  `.gradle\caches\5.6.2\scripts-remapped\build_7tod23iwanax3gvxok38cccwk\avok974yim47bw7y5uibkvy5o\projc2aa9a77c8f22767dac24ce473ea6e20` I solved this error

Answer (score 1):

I removed all

```
 firebase_core: ^0.4.4+2
  firebase_auth: ^0.15.5+2
  cloud_firestore: ^0.13.4
```

and then added them one by one
like
add `firebase_core: ^0.4.4+2` then run the app
add `firebase_auth: ^0.15.5+2` and run the app
and it works I do not know where is the problem but I solved it with that.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I have removed the version of dependencies the error was automatically removed.
before:

```
  firebase_core: ^1.10.0
  firebase_app_check: ^0.0.3
  cloud_firestore: 3.1.0
```

after:

```
  firebase_core: ^1.10.0
  firebase_app_check: ^0.0.3
  cloud_firestore:
```